# API Platform multi DB connection

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

i need a help with symfony....
I'm doing an API in API Platform, but it must be able to connect to several DBs...
meaning, it must receive inside the authentication token the connection ID that'll be used for every action the user will do in the DB...
so, I did this in my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`... obviously I'm not showing the actual connection values

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: sqlsrv
                dbname: db_default
                user: user_default
                password: password_default
                host: host_default
                server_version: '15'
                charset: UTF-8
            conn1:
                driver: sqlsrv
                dbname: db_conn1
                user: user_conn1
                password: password_conn1
                host: host_conn1
                server_version: '15'
                charset: UTF-8
            conn2:
                driver: sqlsrv
                dbname: db_conn2
                user: user_conn2
                password: password_conn2
                host: host_conn2
                server_version: '15'
                charset: UTF-8
            conn3:
                driver: sqlsrv
                dbname: db_conn3
                user: user_conn3
                password: password_conn3
                host: host_conn3
                server_version: '15'
                charset: UTF-8
            conn4:
                driver: sqlsrv
                dbname: db_conn4
                user: user_conn4
                password: password_conn4
                host: host_conn4
                server_version: '15'
                charset: UTF-8
```

so, inside the authentication request, together with the username and password comes also the ID of the connection that I must use to authenticate the user.
but how can I tell symfony which connection to use to authenticate the user ??
or should I make my own custom authenticator ?? I can't find any decent examples on the internet